# h:selectbooleancheckbox click not enabling the next h:selectbooleancheckbox

Tags: jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I am using JSF 2.0. I have two check boxes (both are h:selectBooleanCheckBox). The requirement is to enable the second check box on click of the first check box. Here is how the code looks like:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="chkbox1" 
value="#{dataTableRow.employeeMBean.displayStatus}"
    onclick="updateDisplayStatus(this);return false;">
<a4j:ajax execute="chkbox1" render="chkbox1, chkbox2"></a4j:ajax>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="chkbox2" 
value="#{dataTableRow.employeeMBean.publicStatus}"
    disabled="#{!dataTableRow.employeeMBean.displayStatus}">
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

### JS:

```
function updatePublicStatus(obj){   
    var currentValue = obj.checked;
    updatePublicStatusJS(currentValue);
    if(currentValue == true){
        document.getElementById("summaryForm:solutionsTable:"+solnDtIdx+":editPanel:0:chkbox2").disabled = "false";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("summaryForm:solutionsTable:"+solnDtIdx+":editPanel:0:chkbox2").disabled = "disabled";
    }
}
```

### a4j:jsFunction

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="updatePublicStatusJS" action="#{employeeMBean.updatePublicStatus}"
 render="chkbox2">
<a4j:param name="param1" assignTo="#{dataTableRow.employeeMBean.displayStatus}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

There are two problems:

1. The second check box is not getting enabled on clik of the first
   check box.
2. The action of the `a4j:jsFunction` is never getting
   called.

I am not sure why the second checkbox is not enabled. 
Please let me know if anymore code or explanation is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're enabling the second checkbox using JS but also you are stablishing a `disabled` condition, which makes the checkbox to be enabled/disabled after you make your ajax call. Choose one of them (client side or ajax) to update your second checkbox status, not both.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that and will come back here.

Comment: The root cause was, the '<a4j:jsFunction>' call was not required. I guess that is what you mentioned too.

Comment: It's okey. Then, publish the answer for this post and mark it as resolved.

Comment: sure. posted the answer. I can mark it as answered only tomorrow (stack overflow rule).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause: `<a4j:jsFunction>` was not required. So I removed the onclick and executed the `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` using the `<a4j:ajax execute="@this" render="chkbox2"/>`. This way check box value gets set as soon I select the fist check box and the second check box is rendered with the updated value (because of the 'render' attribute).